# How to merge HighlightField Result and SearchHitField Result in ElasticSearch 0.9

Tags: elasticsearch, merge

My Code is sth like this:

```
{ 
  "took" : 7, 
  "timed_out" : false, 
  "_shards" : { 
    "total" : 5, 
    "successful" : 5, 
    "failed" : 0 
  }, 
  "hits" : { 
    "total" : 2, 
    "max_score" : 0.29792547, 
    "hits" : [ { 
      "_index" : "pim", 
      "_type" : "contact", 
      "_id" : "8a92e6e5335f724b013361dacd1225bd", 
      "_score" : 0.29792547, 
      "fields" : { 
        "id" : "8a92e6e5335f724b013361dacd1225bd", 
        "phone" : [ { 
          "op" : "China Mobile", 
          "number" : "13681011893" 
        }, { 
          "op" : "China Mobile", 
          "number" : "13681011893" 
        }, { 
          "op" : "China Mobile", 
          "number" : "13681011893" 
        } ], 
      }, 
      "highlight" : { 
        "phone.number" : [ "1368101189<span class=\"hl\">136810</ 
span>3", "1368101189<span class=\"hl\">136810</span>3", 
"1368101189<span class=\"hl\">136810</span>3" ] 
      } 
    }] 
  } 
}
```

**Actually,I want this result:**

```
{ 
  "took" : 7, 
  "timed_out" : false, 
  "_shards" : { 
    "total" : 5, 
    "successful" : 5, 
    "failed" : 0 
  }, 
  "hits" : { 
    "total" : 2, 
    "max_score" : 0.29792547, 
    "hits" : [ { 
      "_index" : "pim", 
      "_type" : "contact", 
      "_id" : "8a92e6e5335f724b013361dacd1225bd", 
      "_score" : 0.29792547, 
      "fields" : { 
        "id" : "8a92e6e5335f724b013361dacd1225bd", 
        "phone" : [ { 
          "op" : "China Mobile", 
          "number" : "<span class=\"hl\">136810</span>11893" 
        }, { 
          "op" : "China Mobile", 
          "number" : "<span class=\"hl\">136810</span>11893" 
        }, { 
          "op" : "China Mobile", 
          "number" : "<span class=\"hl\">136810</span>11893" 
        } ], 
      } 
    }] 
  } 
}
```

**That is to say,we should get the result between the origin source content searched by elasticsearch and highlight content,Does anyone can help me???**